# How to visualize on Venn diagram P(A ∩ B), P(A | B) when A, B is independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, visualization

The equation in question is: P(A, B) = P(A | B) * P(B), and P(A,B) = P(A) * P(B).
You can see in the image the portion of A ∩ B.
[Venn diagram of A intersect B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EprZb.png)

In [A independent from B case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc4Tt.png), you can see that the A ∩ B portion is empty space. So according to the image, P(A ∩ B) = 0, P(A | B) = 0, which is clearly wrong.

The way I intuitively visualize the diagram is: each pixel is a event. If a pixel is in circle A, it belongs to A. If a pixel is in both A and B, it is in A ∩ B. This interpretation is clearly wrong.

**So how to interpret the Vein diagram correctly? How to visualize P(A ∩ B), P(A | B) in the case where A is independent of B ?** 
If possible, could anyone draw an image ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Venn diagrams do not visualize independence.

Comment: If $P(A\cap B)=0$ then A and B are not correlated. It does not necessarily imply that A and B are independent.

Comment: In your second picture you see the case A∩B=0, disjoint sets. Independent sets are never disjoint, because if you know you are in A, then from this info you know you *are not in B*, so A dictates about B.

Comment: @callculus They are correlated.

Comment: Do not confuse the words "Independent" with "Mutually exclusive."  These mean completely different things.  $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (*which would imply that $P(A\cap B)=0$*) is the property that we call being "Mutually exclusive."  In lay terms, it means that the circles for $A$ and $B$ in the venn diagram do not overlap.  On the other hand, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, which is equivalent to the property that $P(A)=P(A\mid B)$, is the property that we call being "Independent."  In lay terms, the ratio of the size of $A$ to the whole space is the same as the ratio of $A$ and $B$'s intersection to $B$.